# ORA-00972: identifier is too long-how to catch this error in exception

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

how to trap this error

'ORA-00972: identifier is too long' in the  exception section

in oracle pl/sql,

could you please give me example

Comment: Unless you're dynamically building the SQL statement, you can't.  That's a compilation error not a runtime error in normal code.  You'd notice the exception when you were creating the code not when you're executing it.

Comment: Hi Justin, could you please provide the example . it will be very useful

Comment: An example of what?  Normally, you'd see this sort of error when you run the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` code that tries to create the procedure with an invalid identifier.  You'd see the error when you tried to create the procedure and you'd fix it just like any other syntax error.  You wouldn't write code to catch it.  Unless you're doing something like dynamically building SQL or PL/SQL.

Comment: Hi Justin , thank you for answer .. i have create a function with a varchar2 parameter  and all exception was handled by it .. also i wanted to catch this , bec if this fucntion/procedure is called form application and what if user enters large string and it will give 'ORA-00972: identifier is too long' error.. so i wanted to handle and write a good message  back instead of error ... thank you again

Comment: Is the front end passing a SQL statement as an input parameter to the function that the function then uses `execute immediate` or `dbms_sql` to dynamically execute?  Otherwise, I'm hard-pressed to see how you would get an ORA-00972 error based on the value of the parameter-- that error should be thrown when you tried to compile the procedure.

Comment: OK, so then you are dynamically building and executing a SQL statement.  Architecturally, that's turning a host of errors that should be compilation errors into much harder to deal with runtime errors.  It also vastly complicates the system, opens you up to SQL injection, and makes managing security rather challenging.  But that explains why you're seeing a compilation error at runtime.

Comment: when I was trying to assign value to (sweet.g:=:package.fucntion('string' );) string in this case 'v' ... I was getting the error .,.

Comment: Hi Justin, any hope on above error  thank you in advance

Comment: Bob gave you an answer that works when you're dynamically executing SQL statement so I'm not sure what you're asking.  I'm merely pointing out that the vast, vast majority of the time, this error should be a compilation error (and thus uncatchable) rather than a runtime error (which, as Bob shows you, can be caught).

Answer (score 2):

The way to trap any exception is to initialize an EXCEPTION variable with the proper exception number (-972 in this case) and then use it in an EXCEPTION block:

```
DECLARE
  excpIdentifier_too_long  EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(excpIdentifier_too_long, -972);
BEGIN
  NULL;  -- whatever
EXCEPTION
  WHEN excpIdentifier_too_long THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Do something useful here');
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Hi Bob, why this error wont come under  'when others ' exceptions sections

Comment: I suppose you can handle it that way if you prefer. In that case you should do something like 'WHEN OTHERS IF SQLCODE = -973 THEN NULL; /* do whatever's needed to handle the exception */`. Best of luck.